# How to keep Tkinter frame size unchanged after adding items

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to horizontally divide one line into multiple areas evenly and place items in them, but came across some problems. If I run the code below, the area is evenly divided into three parts.

```
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()

command_area = Frame(tk, pady=10)
command_area.pack(side=TOP)

width = 300
info_area = Frame(command_area, bg='blue', height=50, width=width)
info_area.pack(side=LEFT)
button_area = Frame(command_area, bg='yellow', height=50, width=width)
button_area.pack(side=LEFT)
time_area = Frame(command_area, bg='green', height=50, width=width)
time_area.pack(side=LEFT)


tk.mainloop()
```

However, if I add some item into any of those frames, the width of the frame will change. For example, if I add

```
bomb_label = Label(info_area, text='A sentence')
bomb_label.pack()
```

before "tk.mainloop()", the first area is shortened. How can I keep the sizes of those frames still the same after I add items to them? Thanks.

Comment: You should use ```place``` because ```pack()``` resizes the parent According to the widget inside it

Comment: How about `info_area.pack_propagate(0)` ?

Comment: @Sujay: `place` is one option, but not the only option. I don't think it's correct to say they _should_ use `place`. Rather, they _can_.

Comment: If you have a 100 pixel wide frame, and put a widget that is wider than 100 pixels in it, what  do you expect to happen? Should all frames expand equally, or should the widget be forced to shrink so that it will fit?

Comment: @Sujay I tried place() but there seemed to be some problems. The widgets disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of at least three ways to accomplish your goal. Each method has strengths and weaknesses. Since your question is somewhat vague it's hard to say which method is best.

I think, however, that `grid` is the best choice. It allows you to specify that rows and/or columns must have a uniform size. That, combined with giving all columns equal weight will yield the results you want.

To create uniform-width columns you need to use the `uniform` option, and give every column the same value. The value doesn't matter, since all columns with the same value will be forced to be the same size.

In the following example, I also give each column the same non-zero `weight`, which will allow any extra space to be equally distributed among the columns. That lets the columns grow if the user resizes the window.

```
command_area.pack(side=TOP, fill="x")
command_area.grid_columnconfigure((0,1,2), uniform="1", weight=1)

info_area.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
button_area.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ew")
time_area.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="ew")
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: According to what you said, the `uniform` option gives every column the same size. But what if I try to make the size of every other column the same as the first one? In other words, what if I also want the second and the third columns to be shortened as well after I put items into the first column?

Comment: @zhmff: that's what `uniform` does - it guarantees that all of the columns are of a uniform width. If one shrinks, they all shrink. If one grows, they all grow.